# If cell1 is+500 or -500 the value of any of the cells in range1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Really stuck on a problem here!

I have a large column of numbers and i would like to see if every cell in that column lies between a range of specific numbers.
for example column 1 (column containing the query number) looks like this:

```
189862
205642
225730
231542
```

Here is an image of thhe column of data. 
http://imgur.com/ZsSXuc1

And i would like to see which range those numbers fall into.
the ranges look like this:

```
29844   31375
30639   32284
31481   32610
32721   34525
34696   37214
```

http://imgur.com/HzFTNwB
Another way of saying what i would liek to do is:

I would like to ask this question, for every cell in the highlighted column in picture 1: "Does this value lie inbetween the 2 values highlighted on sheet 'ent', and if so, mark where it matches"
Its the multiplicity of the problem that is stumping me!

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you please include the formula you are using?

Comment: The formulae i am using? im not sure where to begin. I think i need to use a countifs formulae and this formulae:

Comment: =if(A1=MEDIAN(A1:A3),"Yes","No"), which i found here http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/24/between-formula-excel/ . I am trying to work it out in VBA at the moment...

Comment: Can you maybe provide a screenshot how your data is setup?

Comment: I have updated it with pictures :)